# High Sierra and Homebrew not playing nice for GPG

Tags: macos, homebrew, gnupg

Mac OS High Sierra (10.13.6) here. I am trying to get Homebrew to install `gpg` and `gpg-agent` and am running into issues. Running:

```
brew install gpg gpg-agent
```

generates the following output:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "gpg-agent" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Any ideas what the fix is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `gpg-agent` you need to install `gnupg`, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435650/gpg-agent-not-found-for-homebrew) for details, also you can try [gpgtools](https://gpgtools.org) which includes gpg-agent.